# Using image markers to differentiate assets in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a very newbie to Augmented Reality software. I want to design a simple app. As a part of this app, There will be a series of uniquely designed tags. These tags will be on some assets. In the application, I want to store some metadata for each asset. Imagine a DB table with fields like :(asset Id, name, var1, var2...) holding the asset meta-data.

So, when The augmented reality app detects a unique image then it will show its meta-data information, over the marker. It is that simple. In summary, I want to know how can I use image markers to differentiate assets? Sorry If I am asking a very basic question.

Regards,
Ferda

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is too broad. How are you planning to implement this application? First, you have to decide whether you will be using an Augmented Reality SDK or computer vision techniques?

My suggestions would be based on amount of devices you want to use this application or target platform, choosing 1 SDK from ARCore, Vuforia or ARKit. I am not familiar with ARKit but in ARCore and Vuforia, either augmented images or image targets are hold in an image database. So you can get the image id or name of any target you detected using your device. In conclusion you can visualize specific assets for specific images.

Below you can see ARCore Augmented Image database. As you can see every image has a name. In your code you can differentiate images using `image.Name`, then visualize corresponding meta data over the marker.

Also in both SDKs, you can define your own database but your images should not have repetitive features and have high contrast sections.

[image: ARCore image database]

Vuforia has a similar concept as well. The difference between ARCore and Vuforia depends on what which devices you target and quality of image tracking. Vuforia can detect images better in my opinion. It is really fast in terms of detecting images.

Comment: Thank you, Ali, for the detailed answer. I was planning to use Vuforia and unity together. Cause the tutorials that I have examined so far, use this combination. What did you mean by "Which devices you target ?" part. Does it correspond to the asset? How does it matter?

Comment: Because ARCore supports less [devices](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices) than Vuforia and most developers prefer Vuforia over ARCore because of this feature. I would also recommend Vuforia because it is better for the scenario you have in mind.

Comment: Thank you again Ali. I will check this configuration again.